# Use of 'Have' in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Is the word 'have' required in this sentence or is it just meaningless here?

> Yet I have had to watch him surpass me time and time again!

Would removing 'have' from the sentence change its meaning in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does make a difference. Don't be confused by the **had** in there: it's part of **had to** - the past of **have to** - which means **must**.

> Yet I had to watch him surpass me time and time again!

This is past simple: It means that you did have to watch him surpass you, maybe for a while, but it finished some time ago.

> Yet I **have** had to watch him surpass me time and time again!

This is present perfect simple: it means that you had to watch him surpass you in the past, and **it is still happening!**

Comment: I  can't help looking for an exclamation mark at the end. Your last sentence reminds me of [Baby Bear's great line in Goldilocks...](http://www.dltk-teach.com/rhymes/goldilocks_story.htm) *"Someone's been sleeping in my bed **and she's still there!**"*

Comment: The sentence was, actually,  said by Majin Vageta to Goku after their battle with each other in GBA's game `Dragon Ball Z : Buu's Fury`. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @FumbleFingers: your wish is my command.

Comment: @7_R3X,JavaLatte: I always liked reading that line to my kids when it was time for bedtime stories (they probably made me read that story more than most, simply because they could tell ***I*** liked it too! :) It's just such a quirky combination of meaning+verb tenses that it always makes me smile!